# Map object to new object of a different structure C#

Tags: c#, mapping, .net-4.5

I have a web service that returns all the data I need in JSON, just in a structure that isn't very useful. Here's an example:

```
public class Alt
{
    public Member Member { get; set; }
    public Claim OriginalClaim { get; set; }
    public Claim AlternativeClaim { get; set; }
    public decimal Savings { get; set; }
}

public class Member
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Claim
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime EventDate { get; set; }
    public decimal Cost { get; set; }
}
```

I have restructured this in the service I am building in order to cycle through each AlternativeClaim for each Member/OriginalClaim. Here's the new structure:

```
public class Alternative
{
    public Member Member { get; set; }
    public Claim OriginalClaim { get; set; }
    public List<AlternativeClaim> AlternativeClaims { get; set; }
}

public class Member
{
    (same as above)
}

public class Claim
{
    (same as above)
}

public class AlternativeClaim
{
    public Claim AltClaim { get; set; }
    public decimal Savings { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a method or approach available that anyone can suggest that would make mapping to this updated structure simple/able to be done with minimal code? I've used [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki) for things like this before, but I can't think of a way to make that work in this instance. I'm trying to avoid explicitly mapping the data to the model, but will do it if it's unavoidable.

Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you just parse the data manually, it seems something that is trivial and the simpliest solution in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are looking for. This is not really something that can just magically be mapped. Libraries like Automapper can map it over based on naming convention, or attributes, but for the most part you just need to make conversion methods.

Stop over-thinking it, and just make it work!

Comment: I wasn't quite looking for magic - just a way that doesn't end up being a huge wall of difficult-to-maintain code. I didn't want to end up explicitly mapping the objects because that doesn't scale very well. As it is there are nearly 100 properties that make up the objects I'm trying to map to in my real project.